# Why won't my failure flow initiate when SSIS sequence container fails?

Tags: ssis, containers, sequence, constraints, operator-precedence

I have some SSIS sequence containers, and if any of the tasks in them fail I want to direct the flow to a SQL task that cleans everything up so I can address the issue and run it again without having duplicate data.  My problem is that I can't get the flow directed into the SQL task even when something in one of the sequence containers fails.  Seems like this should be the default behavior, but there must be some setting I'm mising.  I played with setting FailParentOnFailure, but all this does is stops the rest of the package from running.  I would insert an image to help with understanding what I have set up, but guess my reputation isn't good enough yet.  :P

Comment: You can always link to an offsite host like twitpic or another provider like that. Otherwise, describe how you are attempting error handling beyond fiddling with the FailParentOnFailure setting.

Comment: Basically all I have is a few data flow tasks inside a sequence container.  If any of those data flow tasks fail (if say the text file I'm trying to load to the database isn't available) then I want the sequence container to then follow the 'failure' precedence constraint instead of the 'success' one.  But instead of doing either it just kills the whole package.  If it doesn't follow the 'failure' precedence constraint by default on an error then I don't understand what the point of having a failure precedence constraint is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think in this definitely one instance where a picture would have helped others answer my question.  I had 3 sequence containers all pointed to the same SQL task if they failed.  I wanted the SQL task to run if ANY of the sequence containers had an error, so the precedence constraints had to be set to a logical OR, otherwise it would never run unless all 3 happened to fail.  Changed it to OR and it worked just like I wanted.

Comment: I have a single container which if fails I want the package to execute another container for logging and email notification. I have set the flow to failure instead of success and added event handler for package on error which populates error description to a variable. The package seems to fail anyway without going to the failure container. Can you advice?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you click Edit on the Constraints and change the last portion for Multiple Constraints to OR so that if any of them fail they execute the task, otherwise it will wait for all of them to fail.

Answer (score 4):

Check the sequence container property if FailPackageOnFailure=true it will not fire "failure precedence constraint".

Answer (score 1):

Without more details on your Sequence Containers it is hard to be sure about the problem.

I would try to check the `Propagate` system variable of your containers. 
Whenever you have a task that can fail and you dont want your whole package to stop, make sure you do one of the following:

- Go to  `Event Handlers` and do something on the `OnError` event to
  treat the failure or
- Set the `Propagate` System Variable of that task to `False`

I would provide some screenshots, but i do not have enough rep for that. Instead i leave you with some links with more information about this subject:

Similar to your question: http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.com/2010/12/ssis-foreach-loop-container-continue-on.html

Detailed info about event propagation: http://simonworth.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/ssis-event-handler-variables-propagate/

Comment: Does that mean I have to set up an OnError event handler for each of my sequence containers?  I just want a failure on any of them to be directed to a single SQL task to remove anything already inserted into the DB.  My sequence containers simply have several data flow tasks in them, nothing fancy.  (see my comment above)

Comment: Id say you could simply set the `propagate` system variable on each of the sequence containers "OnError" events to _false_. That should make your sequence containers redirect the work flow to the sql task without stopping the whole package.

Comment: Just so I understand right, you're saying to create an OnError event handler for the sequence container, but leave it empty and set the propagate sys var to false?  Or does there actually need to be at least one task in the event handler?

Comment: Nevermind, I answered my own question on this issue.  Thanks for the help, though.